# DSP TMS320 change in register

Tags: c, embedded, texas-instruments

I'm trying to program a DSP from Texas, the TMS320 family, using CCStudio 3.3. I'm trying to communicate with Modbus protocol with oher device, but one of the memory registers is changing value all the time.

This is were I initilize the register:

```
conf.Input_Regs.Num_Input_Regs=i;       ///(126)
```

In this case, `i=126`, the number of register in the modbus map.

The initialization goes well, but when I visualize the value of this register in real time, this value is always changing, even sometimes takes negatives values, but the variable is `Uint16`.

I never assign a different value to this variable in the code and I don't know what could happen, if this is an internal problem of the DSP or if it's something in my code, I don't know really much about the internal functioning of the DSPs.

If somebody have any idea that I can try, I will be very grateful.

Comment: You do know that modbus is a serial communication protocol.  Where the external device contains all the registers. Where communication is via messages.  Where each message contains 1) device address 2) function 3) some multiple of 8bit data bytes 4) a checksum.   Therefore, regarding the TMS320 family of DSPs, All the DSP contains is the serial port (UART) and the slave device contains all the MODBUS registers.  So the DSP can try to write to registers, but the value read from the registers depends only on the external device

Comment: please post which MODBUS device and perhaps a link to the register map for that device.

Comment: the 'useful' registers in a MODBUS device are usually in the 40000 through 50000 address range,  not at the 126 address.

Comment: " I don't know really much about the internal functioning of the DSPs" is a very bad start for programming a/the DSP! In fact you will definitively not accomplish anythisng useful without getting comfortable with it. Best is to start with the reference manual/users guide (or what else it is called), then possibly app-notes. The datasheet might also become handy. You also should understand ModBus, of course.

Comment: Bear in mind too that processor registers might be write-only, or have a different function on read.

Comment: From TMS32010 to TMS320C6600, TMS320 is a amazingly HUGE family of distinct configurations.